# Algorithm to count the time that occured on the same period

Tags: vb.net, algorithm

I have already made an algorithm for the problem but it still got a trouble.

Suppose that I have the recap of schedule (contains on gridview named GV):

```
TimeStart  TimeEnd   TotalOccuredOnThisTime
----------------------------------------------
08.00      08.50     1
08.00      09.40     43
08.00      10.50     2
```

Pls take a look to the picture below for more clear information:
[image]

What I want to get from the algorithm is, to count the time that occured on the same period, e.g. on the time of 08.00, it's occured 46 event (see the yellow colored row).

This is my algorithm:

```
Dim ColumnLength As Integer = GV.Rows.Count
Dim TimeStart(ColumnLength - 1) As Integer
Dim TimeEnd(ColumnLength - 1) As Integer
Dim Total(ColumnLength - 1) As Integer

For i = 0 to ColumnLength - 1
  TimeStart(i) = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(GV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text, ".", ""))
  TimeEnd(i) = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Replace(GV.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text, ".", ""))
  Total(i) = 0
Next 

For i = 0 To ColumnLength - 2
  For j = 0 To ColumnLength - 1        
    If TimeEnd(i) > TimeStart(j) And ((TimeStart(i) <= TimeEnd(j)) Or (TimeStart(i) >= TimeEnd(j))) 
      Total(j) = Total(j) - Total(i)
    End If
  Next
Next
```

But it's resulted the wrong value.

The result what I want is like:

```
Time: 08.00 - 08.50   --> 46 event occured
      08.50 - 09.40   --> 46 event occured
      09.40 - 10.00   --> 45 event occured
      etc...
```

How to do that properly? Really need your help...

Comment: `((TimeStart(i) <= TimeEnd(j)) Or (TimeStart(i) >= TimeEnd(j))` is always true

Comment: You should show us more of your code, what are `ColumnLength`,`TimeStart`, `TimeEnd` and `Total`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I have edited the question. Please take a look. Thx :)

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: is this Winforms or ASP.NET? Why do you use the GridView instead of the DataSource directly,  normally you should use the dbms to do such calculations. But even if you want to do it on the client, it would be better to use the underlying DataSource (f.e. a DataTable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`Dictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x525za90.aspx#Y456) to keep track of the time ranges by concatenating the two time strings together for the `Key` (no need to cast to integers), and then for each occurrence of that range you could increment the `Value` portion of the `Dictionary`.

Additionally, there is no need to have nested loops using this approach, or a staging loop to populate start and end time arrays. The following algorithm should provide the results you are looking for:

```
Dim columnLength As Integer = GV.Rows.Count
Dim timeRangeCount As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

For i = 0 to columnLength - 1
  Dim timeStart As String = GV.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text
  Dim timeEnd As String = GV.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text
  Dim key As String = String.Format("{0}-{1}", timeStart, timeEnd)

  If timeRangeCount.ContainsKey(key)
      timeRangeCount(key) += 1
  Else
      timeRangeCount(key) = 1
  End If
Next
```

Thus you could pull the count of the time range 09.40 - 10.00, for example, from the dictionary by saying:

```
Dim totalOccuredOnThisTime As Integer = timeRangeCount("09.40-10.00")
```

---

I've **verified** this algorithm with the similar test code:

```
Dim columnLength As Integer = 6
Dim timeStart() As String = {"08.00", "08.00", "10.00", "08.00", "08.00", "10.00"}
Dim timeEnd() As String = {"08.50", "08.50", "11.00", "09.00", "08.50", "11.00"}
Dim timeRangeCount As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

For i = 0 to columnLength - 1
  Dim key As String = String.Format("{0}-{1}", timeStart(i), timeEnd(i))

  If timeRangeCount.ContainsKey(key)
      timeRangeCount(key) += 1
  Else
      timeRangeCount(key) = 1
  End If
Next

Console.WriteLine(timeRangeCount)
```

[image]

### Update

After reading your clarification in your comment, you can still use the Dictionary to help keep track of this along with a couple helper classes (`TimeRange`, `TimeRangeCounter`, and `TimeRangeEqualityComparer`). This does make things a bit more complicated though.

The first helper class is used to hold the counts of exact and sub range matches:

```
Public Class TimeRangeCounter
    Property ExactRangeMatch as Integer
    Property SubRangeMatch as Integer
End Class
```

The second helper class is used to help the dictionary know how one key (of type `TimeRange`) differs from another:

```
Public Class TimeRangeEqualityComparer 
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TimeRange)

    Public Overloads Function Equals(left As TimeRange, right As TimeRange) _
            As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TimeRange).Equals           

        Return left.ToString = right.ToString   
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetHashCode(range As TimeRange) _
            As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TimeRange).GetHashCode

        return range.ToString().GetHashCode()
    End Function

End Class
```

The Third helper class stores the start and end times of a range:

```
Public Class TimeRange 
    Private readonly _start
    Private readonly _end

    Public Readonly Property Start 
        Get
           return _start
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Readonly Property [End] 
        Get
           return _end
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(start As String, [end] As string)
        Me._start = start
        Me._end = [end]
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() as String
       Return String.Format("{0}-{1}", Start, [End])
    End Function

End Class
```

So using the above we should be able to write this algorithm:

```
Dim columnLength As Integer = 5
Dim timeStart() As String = {"08.00", "08.00", "10.00", "08.00", "08.00"}
Dim timeEnd() As String = {"08.50", "11.50", "11.00", "09.00", "08.50"}
Dim comparer As New TimeRangeEqualityComparer()
Dim timeRangeCounts As New Dictionary(Of TimeRange, TimeRangeCounter)(comparer)

'Count exact range matches while building dictionary
For i = 0 to columnLength - 1
  Dim key As TimeRange = New TimeRange(timeStart(i), timeEnd(i))

  If timeRangeCounts.ContainsKey(key)
      timeRangeCounts(key).ExactRangeMatch += 1
  Else
      Dim counter =  New TimeRangeCounter()
      counter.ExactRangeMatch = 1
      timeRangeCounts(key) = counter
  End If        

Next           

'Count sub ranges          
For Each kvp in timeRangeCounts
    For Each key in timeRangeCounts.Keys
        If kvp.key.Start >= key.Start AndAlso _ 
           kvp.Key.End <= key.End AndAlso _
           kvp.key.ToString <> key.ToString then           

            kvp.Value.SubRangeMatch += 1
        End If
    Next
Next

Console.WriteLine(timeRangeCounts)
```

Comment: Hi Matt, this is really a new way for me. Thanks, it's brilliant! :)
But this isn't solved the problem. Is there any possible way to do the thing to count the event that occurred on a specific range, 

i.e. 
There is a key: `08.00-08.50, 08.00-09.40`. Then: 
**(1)** I want to count the event that occurred between `08.00-08.50`, so it should return `value:2` --> Because `08.00-08.50` and `08.00-09.40` is on the range of `08.00-08.50`. 
**(2)** Between `08.50-09.40` should return 1 --> Because `08.00-09.40` still on the range. Is there any possible way?

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: I've updated my answer to account for both exact matches and where a given time range happens to be a sub-range of some other time range.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will check the code soon and will let you know it's work or not... :)

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your help. It help me to solved the problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: @pnuts, If my memory serves me right (this answer is 6 years old), it just was an image of the output from Console.WriteLine(timeRangeCounts) when ran from inside LinqPad.