# Bind Dictionary to GridView

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding, gridview, dictionary

Referring to this thread: [Algorithm to count the time that occured on the same period](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975788/algorithm-to-count-the-time-that-occured-on-the-same-period), how to bind the dictionary to the GridView? Pls take a look to the answer.

I tried to add a GridView and then on the code-behind: `GV.DataSource = timeRangeCounts` and bind it, but in return:

`The data source for GridView with id 'GV' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns. Ensure that your data source has content.`

How can I do that? Please take a look at the code below:

---

The first helper class is used to hold the counts of exact and sub range matches:

```
Public Class TimeRangeCounter
    Property ExactRangeMatch as Integer
    Property SubRangeMatch as Integer
End Class
```

The second helper class is used to help the dictionary know how one key (of type `TimeRange`) differs from another:

```
Public Class TimeRangeEqualityComparer 
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TimeRange)

    Public Overloads Function Equals(left As TimeRange, right As TimeRange) _
            As Boolean Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TimeRange).Equals           

        Return left.ToString = right.ToString   
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function GetHashCode(range As TimeRange) _
            As Integer Implements IEqualityComparer(Of TimeRange).GetHashCode

        return range.ToString().GetHashCode()
    End Function

End Class
```

The Third helper class stores the start and end times of a range:

```
Public Class TimeRange 
    Private readonly _start
    Private readonly _end

    Public Readonly Property Start 
        Get
           return _start
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Readonly Property [End] 
        Get
           return _end
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(start As String, [end] As string)
        Me._start = start
        Me._end = [end]
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() as String
       Return String.Format("{0}-{1}", Start, [End])
    End Function

End Class
```

So using the above we should be able to write this algorithm:

```
Dim columnLength As Integer = 5
Dim timeStart() As String = {"08.00", "08.00", "10.00", "08.00", "08.00"}
Dim timeEnd() As String = {"08.50", "11.50", "11.00", "09.00", "08.50"}
Dim comparer As New TimeRangeEqualityComparer()
Dim timeRangeCounts As New Dictionary(Of TimeRange, TimeRangeCounter)(comparer)

'Count exact range matches while building dictionary
For i = 0 to columnLength - 1
  Dim key As TimeRange = New TimeRange(timeStart(i), timeEnd(i))

  If timeRangeCounts.ContainsKey(key)
      timeRangeCounts(key).ExactRangeMatch += 1
  Else
      Dim counter =  New TimeRangeCounter()
      counter.ExactRangeMatch = 1
      timeRangeCounts(key) = counter
  End If        

Next           

'Count sub ranges          
For Each kvp in timeRangeCounts
    For Each key in timeRangeCounts.Keys
        If kvp.key.Start >= key.Start AndAlso _ 
           kvp.Key.End <= key.End AndAlso _
           kvp.key.ToString <> key.ToString then           

            kvp.Value.SubRangeMatch += 1
        End If
    Next
Next

'Console.WriteLine(timeRangeCounts)
    GV.DataSource = timeRangeCounts
    GV.DataBind()
```

The gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Key" HeaderText="Dictionary Key" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="Dictionary Value" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then I tried to run it but the result is like:

```
Dictionary Key    Dictionary Value
08:00:00-08:50:00 TimeRangeCounter
08:00:00-09:40:00 TimeRangeCounter
10:00:00-11:40:00 TimeRangeCounter
...               ...
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Please show the code for your Gridview, thanks!

Comment: @Brian Webster: Sorry for the late reply. I added it. Pls take a look. It got the results but the Dictionary Value doesn't return any value, it returns only `TimeRangeCounter`.

Comment: Did the addition of a `ToString()` override help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is a Gridview**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Key" HeaderText="Dictionary Key" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="Dictionary Value" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

**Here is code to bind a dictionary to that Gridview**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim D As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)
    D.Add(1, "One")
    D.Add(2, "Two")
    D.Add(3, "Three")
    GV.DataSource = D
    GV.DataBind()
End Sub
```

**Here is the output**

[image]

**What if my Value of of some type "MyClass?"**

The Gridview will execute the `ToString` function of `MyClass`, per "Value" cell.

In your example, Override the `ToString` function on this class

```
Public Class TimeRangeCounter
    Property ExactRangeMatch as Integer
    Property SubRangeMatch as Integer
End Class
```

This is necessary because your "Value" is of time `TimeRangeCounter`

**Summary**

The Author's code had two problems.

- Problem 1 was generating an actual error and was solved by following my code example
- Problem 2 was the lack of a ToString function for the custom class used in the "Value" column of the Gridview

Comment: I tried to assign the Dictionary to the GridView but it still returns the message. Pls take a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975788/algorithm-to-count-the-time-that-occured-on-the-same-period .. Thanks :)

Comment: Please edit your question to include your exact code. The question and answers in your link are a bit ambiguous with regards to which code I should be looking at. This code that I have posted works. Also, it's good to have questions/answers on SO be distinct units of work so that passersby don't have to go hunting down information that is required to understand what is being asked.