# Setting a dictionary as datasource

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have the following dictionary and like to set this as the datasource to my Gridview in my asp.net page

```
Dim myList As New Dictionary(Of Person, string)
```

the dictionary key is an object of `Person` which has Id,FirstName and LastName.
and I like to bind the above dictionary to a gridview which shows **First name**, **Last name** and **Address**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName">
    <EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

the next column will be last name and the third will be the address - which is the value property of dictionary

is it possible to bind the above dictionary to a gridview at all?

Thank you.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10378075/127880

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind Dictionary to GridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377486/bind-dictionary-to-gridview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Dictionary` is made up of KeyValuePair elements, which exposes two properties: `Key` and `Value`.

Since you want to bind items that are accessible through the `Key` property of each `Dictionary` entry, you should reference these properties in your databinding as `Key.FirstName`, `Key.LastName`, `Key.Address`, etc.

So given your example above, binding the TextBox should look like:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Key.FirstName")%>'></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I can display the name as you mentioned but it was erroring in SortExpression and I had to remove it to work `<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName">`, any idea how to assign sortexpression?

Comment: Did you try setting the sortExpression to `Key.FirstName`?

Comment: actually it was DataKeyNames not sortexpression. I managed to do without it. thanks for your help