# Bind gridview column data to specific dictionary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dictionary, datasource

I have a list of objects, part of which is a dictionary. I'm dynamically adding a column to the GridView for each different key in the dictionaries. How do I bind the data in that column to dictionary value for that key? Not all dictionaries will have the same keys/values. Can I use BoundFields or do I have to use template fields? Thanks!

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377486/bind-dictionary-to-gridview

Comment: @Sam My question is different, I do not want the keys and values as rows. I want the keys as columns and the values inside the rows of their respective column.